# How to get element from collection in Meteor if it multi-dimensional array or object or both?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have collection "groups". like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "e9sc7ogDp8pwY2uSX",
    "groupName" : "one",
    "creator" : "KPi9JwvEohKJsFyL4",
    "eventDate" : "",
    "isEvent" : true,
    "eventStatus" : "Event announced",
    "user" : [
                            {
                                "id" : "xfaAjgcSpSeGdmBuv",
                                "username" : "1@gmail.com",
                                "email" : "1@gmail.com",
                                "order" : [ ],
                                "price" : [ ],
                                "confirm" : false,
                                "complete" : false,
                                "emailText" : ""
                            },
                ...

            ],
     ...

    "buyingStatus" : false,
    "emailTextConfirmOrder" : " With love, your Pizzaday!! "
}
```

How can I get a value of specific element? For example i need to get value of "Groups.user.confirm" of specific group and specific user.

I tried to do so in methods.js

```
'pizzaDay.user.confirm': function(thisGroupeId, thisUser){
    return Groups.find({ _id: thisGroupeId },{"user": ""},{"id": thisUser}).confirm 
},
```

but it returns nothing.

Even in mongo console I can get just users array using

```
db.groups.findOne({ _id: "e9sc7ogDp8pwY2uSX"},{"user": ""})
```

The whole code is github 
http://github.com/sysstas/pizzaday2

Comment: What you are trying to do using `find({ _id: thisGroupeId },{"user": ""},{"id": thisUser})`? Why `{"id": thisUser}` is added in the `find` query?

Comment: I think you need to go for `aggreagte`, to achieve what you want. Please try searching here, you will get some solution.

Comment: "thisUser" contains "xfaAjgcSpSeGdmBuv". I trying to find value of "confirm" or other users values.

Comment: The query you are trying is not right. You need to use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to get the desired result.

Comment: can You please help me to make the correct querry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using this:

```
Template.Pizzaday.helpers({
 confirm: function(){     
  let isConfirm = Groups.findOne(
    {_id: Session.get("idgroupe")}).user.filter(
      function(v){
        return v.id === Meteor.userId();
      })[0].confirm;
  return isConfirm;    
 },
});
```

But I still think that there is some much elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:-

```
db.groups.aggregate(
[ 
{
  $match: 
  {
    _id: thisGroupeId,
    "user.id": thisUser
  }
},
{
    $project:
    {
        groupName : 1,
        //Add other fields of `user` level, if want to project those as well.
        user:
        {
            "$setDifference":
            [{
                "$map":
                {
                  "input": "$user",
                  "as": "o",
                  "in":
                  {
                      $eq : ["$$o.id" , thisUser] //Updated here
                  }
                }
            },[false]
            ]
        }
    }
 }
]);
```

The above query will give the object(s) matching the query in `$match` inside `user` array. Now you can access any field you want of that particular object.

Comment: seems like ( "user.id": thisUser )- doing nothint. If I take just $match part in aggregate it returns me the whole groupe.  Nothing change if I add ( "user.id": thisUser )

Comment: first is
 "$cond":[
                      {
                        {
                          _id: thisGroupeId,
                          "user.id": thisUser
                        }
                      },
                      "$$o",false]
seems like we no need doble braces

Comment: if I fix it to "$cond":[ {  _id: thisGroupeId, "user.id": thisUser  }, "$$o",false]
it throws

Comment: assert: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath 'e9sc7ogDp8pwY2uSX' doesn't start with $",
 "code" : 16873,
 "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed

Comment: Error: command failed: { "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath 'e9sc7ogDp8pwY2uSX' doesn't start with $",
 "code" : 16873,
 "ok" : 0} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:244:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1149:12)
    at (shell):1:11 2016-06-06T10:33:44.717+0300 Error: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath 'e9sc7ogDp8pwY2uSX' doesn't start with $", "code" : 16873,"ok" : 0} : aggregate failed at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you check the updated query?

Comment: assert: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$$o.id'",
 "code" : 15999,
 "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$$o.id'",
 "code" : 15999,
 "ok" : 0

Comment: maybe Meteor Mongo have some difference with pure Mongo?

Comment: Can you look into [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and try solving the issue? The query in the answer should work properly, as I am using it in my codes. I have no idea about Meteor Mongo.

Comment: Ill try. But I think there should be some simple way how to resolve my problem. Because it's easy to insert, change and remove items, so I think there should be some another way...

Comment: @StanislavSysoiev I have updated the query again. This time it should run properly. There was syntax error in the query.

Answer (score 0):

'pizzaDay.user.confirm': function(){
    return Groups.findOne({ _id: thisGroupeId }).user.confirm;

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yes. It will works if there is only one user in collection. but how to find "confirm" value of specific user?